# Modal Popup visible with wrong Dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, modalpopupextender

My modal Popup is not working correctly. When I run the application on my local machine everything works fine, but as soon as I try to run the website from the server, the modal popups display whenever a selectedindexchanged event took place. I've gone through the code but just don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've done a lot of modals, it's just for this application it is not working correctly... The modal popup should not be visible when the selectedIndexChanged events take place on the form, except when the item is selected....

[image]

The again if the selectedIndexChanged event was changed this popup displays and I select the edit button of the record, the modalpopup displays as it should, but still with same popup visible on the background....

[image]

I've tried adding (!IsNotPostback) in the click event's but still not working....

This is how my popup looks like:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnBaseStock" runat="server" />
         <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalBaseStock" runat="server" 
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True"
            Enabled="True" PopupControlID="pnlBaseStock" TargetControlID="hdnBaseStock" CancelControlID ="btnCancelBaseStock">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
         <asp:Panel ID="pnlBaseStock" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="404px" Height="271px">
            <table style="width: 401px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" Text="Warehouse"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstWareHouseEdit" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="255px" 
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstWareHouseEdit_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="label7" runat="server" Text="Customer"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLookupCust" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="label8" runat="server" Text="Site"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLookupSite" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="label4" runat="server" Text="Vendor No"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtVendorNo" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="label5" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="46px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="label6" runat="server" Text="Actual Qty"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtActualQty" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="label9" runat="server" Text="BaseQty"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBaseQty" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveEdit" BackColor="White" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="153px" OnClick="btnSaveEdit_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelBaseStock" BackColor="White" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="95px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </asp:Panel>
```

And this is my clickEvents of the dropdowns on which they display:

```
    protected void lstWarehouseNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            lstVendorNo.SelectedIndex = 0;
            PopulateFilterBaseStock();

    }

    protected void lstVendorNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            lstWarehouseNo.SelectedIndex = 0;
            PopulateFilterBaseStock();
    }
```

Can somebody please point out to me what I'm doing wrong or any suggestions??

Comment: how it is working on your local machine?

Comment: Hi SMK, yes on my local machine everything works fine, the modal popup doesn't display until you select the edit button which is correct... On local it works perfect, it's on server side where it is not....